# Jquery trigger ajax remotely

Tags: jquery, ajax, triggers

I am writing some ajax code which will fetch updated information from my database.

However, I don't want to write my code to fetch updates at regular intervals. **I wonder if it is possible to trigger the ajax code remotely?**

Comment: sounds like node.js :) but this could be a bit overdone. Alternative is to poll for changes...

Comment: google "ajax long pooling" or "ajax comet", but all they do is send requests at intervals and wait for an answer . so in short you can't until html5 sockets will be implemented in brosers but you'll still have problems on older browsers ( nothing new here )

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with recent improvements in modern browsers which support web sockets. But for backwards compatibility you would need to look at using something like SignalR which uses Ajax polling to simulate a continuous connection.

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Here are some links about polling:

http://ajaxpatterns.org/Periodic_Refresh

http://www.nickriggs.com/posts/simple-ajax-polling-plugin-for-jquery/

Comment: I'd add that both are non-trivial and can have issues with scalability. Better to poll unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: Can you tell me what 'polling' is accompanied by a url to readup on the subject, please?

Comment: OK added some links about polling